# Trying to get topography via elevation package Python

Tags: python, dem, elevation, topography

So I'm trying to get some topography. In Detail some parts of the panama canal. I tried using the elevation python package. Here is my code so far:

```
import elevation

min_lat, max_lat = 8.0, 9.5
min_lon, max_lon = -80.0, -79.5

elevation.clip(bounds=(min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat), output='panama_canal.tif', product = "SRTM1")
```

Every time I try to run the script I get this error:

```
  File "c:\Users\morit\Documents\SS2023\NMWC\Projekt\topo_panama_script.py", line 11, in <module>
    elevation.clip(bounds=(min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat), output='panama_canal.tif', product = "SRTM1")
  File "C:\Users\morit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\elevation\datasource.py", line 216, in clip
    datasource_root = seed(bounds=bounds, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\morit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\elevation\datasource.py", line 188, in seed
    ensure_tiles(datasource_root, ensure_tiles_names, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\morit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\elevation\datasource.py", line 148, in ensure_tiles
    return util.check_call_make(path, targets=['download'], variables=variables_items, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\morit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\elevation\util.py", line 88, in check_call_make
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
  File "C:\Users\morit\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'make -C C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\bopen\elevation\Cache\SRTM1 download ENSURE_TILES="N08/N08W080.tif N09/N09W080.tif"' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

What could my problem be? I tried running it on different OS and different environments. My guess is the download of data is not working properly...

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed all the dependencies ( see [Pypy elevation](https://pypi.org/project/elevation/)) because it works on Linux and Mac)

```
import elevation
min_lat, max_lat = 8.0, 9.5
min_lon, max_lon = -80.0, -79.5
elevation.clip(bounds=(min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat), output='panama_canal.tif', product = "SRTM1")
curl -s -o spool/N08/N08W080.hgt.gz.temp https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/skadi/N08/N08W080.hgt.gz && mv spool/N08/N08W080.hgt.gz.temp spool/N08/N08W080.hgt.gz
gunzip spool/N08/N08W080.hgt.gz 2>/dev/null || touch spool/N08/N08W080.hgt
gdal_translate -q -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co PREDICTOR=2 spool/N08/N08W080.hgt cache/N08/N08W080.tif 2>/dev/null || touch cache/N08/N08W080.tif
curl -s -o spool/N09/N09W080.hgt.gz.temp https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/skadi/N09/N09W080.hgt.gz && mv spool/N09/N09W080.hgt.gz.temp spool/N09/N09W080.hgt.gz
gunzip spool/N09/N09W080.hgt.gz 2>/dev/null || touch spool/N09/N09W080.hgt
gdal_translate -q -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co PREDICTOR=2 spool/N09/N09W080.hgt cache/N09/N09W080.tif 2>/dev/null || touch cache/N09/N09W080.tif
rm spool/N08/N08W080.hgt spool/N09/N09W080.hgt
gdalbuildvrt -q -overwrite SRTM1.vrt cache/N08/N08W080.tif cache/N09/N09W080.tif cache/N41/N41E012.tif
cp SRTM1.vrt SRTM1.5e9dea2f97ae4c62998f96c35518d6d6.vrt
gdal_translate -q -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co PREDICTOR=2 -projwin -80.0 9.5 -79.5 8.0 SRTM1.5e9dea2f97ae4c62998f96c35518d6d6.vrt panama_canal.tif
rm -f SRTM1.5e9dea2f97ae4c62998f96c35518d6d6.vrt
```

Result

[image]

The module uses make, curl, gunzip, gdal_translate, gdalbuildvrt and rm with [subprocess](https://realpython.com/python-subprocess/)

The error is in file [util.py](https://github.com/bopen/elevation/blob/8b6fd94b5bcc73e1968dc2c98ed259cf87dc864c/elevation/util.py) line 88

```
subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
```

The problem is with the command `make`

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'make -C C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\bopen\elevation\Cache\SRTM1 download ENSURE_TILES="N08/N08W080.tif N09/N09W080.tif"' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Do you have a [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) command (as in Linux or Macos X)?

Comment: I am very certain that i do not have all the right dependencies in my envoirnment. Never the less i found another way: I just downloaded Geo Data from a Webside. I still could try to run it in Linux again. make should work

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me on Windows also then I ran it in a Linux environment (with Python 3.10.6 and Elevation 1.1.3. and its dependencies) and it worked.

I used a wkt file as input and then extracted the bounds first that you need as input for the command.

My code to extract the elevation:

```
# Generate the command with the extracted bounds
command = !eio clip -o OES-DEM3.tif --bounds {min_longitude} 
{min_latitude} {max_longitude} {max_latitude}

# Run the command
subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I found another way. I just downloaded all the data manually on a website. I am going to try it in Linux with the right python version.